# What is ¬ ∈? (negation of ∈)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused with this because in my algebra course when we try to negate a proposition, ∈ don't change. So the quesrion is : what is ¬∈? (if it exists)

Comment: "\notin" ($\notin$).

Comment: should rather be $\notin$ which mean : "not belong to"

Comment: Example: $\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbb N$

Comment: Please give an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably confusing the treatment of hypotheses and conclusions when we negate a statement.

I assume you refer to the fact that the negation of (for instance)
$$\forall x\in X, x\leqslant 1$$
is $\exists x\in X, x> 1$ and not $\exists x\not\in X, x> 1$. That would not make any sense: the contrary of "all elements in $X$ satisfy [some property]" is "there is at least one element in $X$ which does not satisfy [that property]", not "there is some element *not* in $X$ which does not satisfy [that property]".

On the other hand, the negation of
$$\forall x\in X, x\in Y$$
is indeed $\exists x\in X, x\not\in Y$ (and $x\not\in Y$ simply means that $x$ is not in the set $Y$). In other words, we *do* negate $\in$ when negating a statement, but not in the hypotheses.

Comment: thanks a lot it's clear

Comment: @ElieMakdissi, since you accepted this answer, I think it is good to be aware that $\forall x\in X(\dots)$ is a shorthand for $\forall x(x\in X\to \dots)$ and $\exists x\in X(\dots)$ is shorthand for $\exists x(x\in X\land\dots)$. This way, the negation behaves properly on the $\in$ operator as well. Negating $\forall x(x\in X\to\dots)$ results in $\exists x(x\in X\land \lnot\dots)$, in shorthand $\exists x\in X(\lnot\dots)$. Dually, negating $\exists x(x\in X\land\dots)$ becomes $\forall x(x\notin X\lor \lnot\dots)=\forall x(x\in X\to \lnot\dots)$, in shorthand $\forall x\in X(\lnot\dots)$.

Comment: just a question : does $\rightarrow$ means  $\Rightarrow$ in your comment?

Comment: @ElieMakdissi $\to$ means "implies". $A\to B$ means "$A$ implies $B$", or "if $A$, then $B$". This is logically equivalent to saying that $A$ is false or $B$ is true. See also [this page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)

Comment: yep thanks, i was just not familiar with this symbol

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\in$ indicates a set membership; it is not as much as a preposition as it is a relation operator. For instance, you could have a set $X$, and an element of that set $a$, we then say that the relation $a\in X$ is true (e.g. if $X$ is the set of all animals, and $a$ represents a cat, then a is an *element of* $x$).

Conversely, we usually use the relation operator $\notin$ to indicate that something is *not* an element of a set; for example, if $b$ represents a book we say $b\notin X$ is true, since a book is not an animal. Namely,

$$\forall a\left(\lnot(a\in X)\leftrightarrow a\notin X\right).$$

You could define $\lnot\in$ as an operator equivalent to $\notin$ for the same use, but since $\in$ is a relation operator and not a perposition, predicate, etc. it is not customary to negate it.

Comment: Aha thanks a lottt